# Rails Env Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rake

So the other day I was trying to replicate some of the tests that were being ran by circleci and before some of the commands I called:

```
export RAILS_ENV=test
export RACK_ENV=test
```

and now *I guess the problem is that I seem to be stuck in `test`*?

Also,
I've tried executing those same commands except with each of the vars set to development, yet to no avail.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try opening another bash instance.

Comment: @MarekLipka Unfortunately I had already tried that too, but thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Where did you put these environment variables?

Comment: First, I would verify exactly what `RAILS_ENV` and `RACK_ENV` are set to if you're not sure. Run `echo $RACK_ENV` and `echo $RAILS_ENV` to check. Then maybe take a look in `~/.bashrc` and/or `~/.bash_profile` to see if they're being set there.

Answer (score 1):

try 'unsetting' those env variables.

```
export RAILS_ENV=
export RACK_ENV=
```

or try restarting the server to set them back to default.

Comment: okay, so, I unset the variables and then reset the variables to the correct values and now it seems to work..hmm..maybe I wasn't setting the variables appropriately earlier or something, but anyway

Comment: You can probably unset the variables and just run the app, they probably assume reasonable defaults. (Or explicitly give you an error)

Also, you could just MAKE SURE ruby is registering these changes by killing it/re-running 

killall ruby

Or you can go into irb and see what ruby is currently reading them as:

  puts ENV['RAILS_ENV']